# How do I use Index Match to find not only the first instance in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns, one that contain three different text strings "AA, AB, AC" and the other contains numbers. The text strings repeat all the way down the column, so it will look like

```
AA    56
AB    55
AB    54 
AC    2
AA    9
AB    10
AB    11
AB    12
AC    3
```

What I want to produce using a formula is the number next to "AC" every instance in that column. Using Index Match would only give me "2" in this case. I've tried to combine Small and IF to no avail.

Comment: What would your expected outcome look like?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have

Answer (score 0):

With the Dynamic Array formula:

```
=FILTER(B:B,A:A="AC")
```

Dynamic Array Formula are currently only available with Office 365 subscription.

[image]

---

If one does not have that then use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$9)/($A$1:$A$9="AC"),ROW(ZZ1))),"")
```

And copy down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to Scott's, this only works with Office 365, but it puts all of the answers within the same field.  I've assumed your small strings are in column `A` and go from cells `2` to `20`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$20="AC",$B$2:$B$20,""))
```

Press Ctrl + Shift + Enter when you are done inputting the formula (or on a mac, ⌘ + Shift + Return).  This will turn it into an Array formula.

The first argument (`", "`) says to join the fields with commas and spaces, but you can always change this to suit your needs.

Comment: If you have OFFICE 365 you can replace the IF with FILTER, see my answer.